# Python program won't run correctly when opened from folder or desktop, but works fine when run in IDLE

Tags: python, stopwatch, traceback

I have created a simple task-timing program in which the user presses a key to start a timer, and again to stop. The program displays the time elapsed. This all works fine when i run the program, however after this I have the time and task name saved to a file. When run in IDLE (and NetBeans), this save works perfectly. However in the command window, the program closes, not before briefly displaying a traceback error. The data is not saved to the file (which is in the same folder as my program).

Here is the code:

```
*import time
task = input('What task are you completing?\n')
print('Press ENTER to begin. Afterwards, press ENTER to "click" the stopwatch. Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
input()                    
print('Started.')
startTime = time.time()    
lastTime = startTime

while True:
        input()

        totalTime = round(time.time() - startTime, 2)

        totalTime = str(totalTime)

        seconds = int(float(totalTime))

        minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
        hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
        periods = [('hours', hours), ('minutes', minutes), ('seconds', seconds)]
        time_string = ', '.join('{} {}'.format(value, name)
                                for name, value in periods
                                if value)

        print(str(task) + ' took: ' + time_string)
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Saving to file')
        time.sleep(3)



        writefile = open('Timelog.csv','a')
        writefile.write(task + ', ' + time_string + '')
        writefile.close()
        break
end = input('Press enter to close')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: hmm works fine for me using the command line, how are you executing the file and what does the traceback say?

Comment: double-clicking from the folder it is in, unsure as to what the traceback says, only way I can think to check is to record my screen and slow it down. Out of interest, does the data save to a file? (Assuming you created a file with the same name of course)
Thanks

Comment: yes it saves the data to the csv file

Comment: Please post the traceback error too. (I guess that when you are executing your program from within the terminal, you don't have the permission to write your csv file - in contrast to when it runs from the IDE - but that is only a guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any chance that you can open a command-prompt/terminal-session and execute from there?  That would let you grab the trace.

I'm guessing quant has the right of it and you're running into a access/permissions hurdle of some kind.  You can also try saving to a filename that doesn't exist yet; maybe it's just overwriting the file created with the IDE that's is the problem.

Comment: Hi Pete, thanks for this suggestion. I ran it from cmd and lo and behold, no error - the code runs perfectly. Guess that's the way it is - very little a reboot won't solve haha.

Comment: Glad it helped Matt!